# SQL Only display data with Max latest date date

Tags: date, max, filtered-index

| tracking_id | date_action | action_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021/01/24 | 4 |
| 1 | 2021/01/26 | 3 |
| 2 | 2021/01/25 | 67 |
| 2 | 2021/01/24 | 8 |
| 4 | 2021/01/27 | 10 |
| 5 | 2021/01/24 | 6 |
| 4 | 2021/01/25 | 55 |

Result should be:

| tracking_id | date_action | action_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021/01/26 | 3 |
| 2 | 2021/01/25 | 67 |
| 4 | 2021/01/27 | 10 |

Comment: which rdms database do you use aand whuch version of it

Answer (score 0):

This Version is for **MySQL**, but it should work on any  rdms
The subselect get the Max date from the table for every track_id and uses that ti get the wanted row.

But this would select  all rows for that track_id, that have that max date.

If you only want you, you need row_number and an Order

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tracks
>     (`tracking_id` int, `date_action` datetime, `action_id` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tracks
>     (`tracking_id`, `date_action`, `action_id`)
> VALUES
>     (1, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 4),
>     (1, '2021-01-26 01:00:00', 3),
>     (2, '2021-01-25 01:00:00', 67),
>     (2, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 8),
>     (4, '2021-01-27 01:00:00', 10),
>     (5, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 6),
>     (4, '2021-01-25 01:00:00', 55)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM tracks t1
> WHERE `date_action` = (SELECT MAX(`date_action`) FROM tracks WHERE `tracking_id` = t1.`tracking_id`)
> ```
>
> ```
> tracking_id | date_action         | action_id
> ----------: | :------------------ | --------:
>           1 | 2021-01-26 01:00:00 |         3
>           2 | 2021-01-25 01:00:00 |        67
>           4 | 2021-01-27 01:00:00 |        10
>           5 | 2021-01-24 01:00:00 |         6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=abc5a9569e9a9a465fe8450fc3604382)*

And here the same for **Postgres**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tracks
>     ("tracking_id" int, "date_action" timestamp, "action_id" int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tracks
>     ("tracking_id", "date_action", "action_id")
> VALUES
>     (1, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 4),
>     (1, '2021-01-26 01:00:00', 3),
>     (2, '2021-01-25 01:00:00', 67),
>     (2, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 8),
>     (4, '2021-01-27 01:00:00', 10),
>     (5, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 6),
>     (4, '2021-01-25 01:00:00', 55)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM tracks t1
> WHERE "date_action" = (SELECT MAX("date_action") FROM tracks WHERE "tracking_id" = t1."tracking_id")
> ```
>
> ```
> tracking_id | date_action         | action_id
> ----------: | :------------------ | --------:
>           1 | 2021-01-26 01:00:00 |         3
>           2 | 2021-01-25 01:00:00 |        67
>           4 | 2021-01-27 01:00:00 |        10
>           5 | 2021-01-24 01:00:00 |         6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=675dfb8fe27858e84334944b5e290b77)*

andd a Version of it for **SQL Server**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tracks
>     ("tracking_id" int, "date_action" DATETIME, "action_id" int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tracks
>     ("tracking_id", "date_action", "action_id")
> VALUES
>     (1, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 4),
>     (1, '2021-01-26 01:00:00', 3),
>     (2, '2021-01-25 01:00:00', 67),
>     (2, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 8),
>     (4, '2021-01-27 01:00:00', 10),
>     (5, '2021-01-24 01:00:00', 6),
>     (4, '2021-01-25 01:00:00', 55)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM tracks t1
> WHERE "date_action" = (SELECT MAX("date_action") FROM tracks WHERE "tracking_id" = t1."tracking_id")
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> tracking_id | date_action             | action_id
> ----------: | :---------------------- | --------:
>           5 | 2021-01-24 01:00:00.000 |         6
>           4 | 2021-01-27 01:00:00.000 |        10
>           2 | 2021-01-25 01:00:00.000 |        67
>           1 | 2021-01-26 01:00:00.000 |         3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e22cdfcefd7c94c0c45f31a8fdc38924)*